# Getting MySQL Connector/C++ to work with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to build an application using C++, MySQL and Visual studio as my IDE. I managed to get MySQL service up and running and I've already started to design my database so I know that the server is up and running on localhost without issues.

Now, I downloaded the MySQL Connector/C++ and I followed the documentation laid out by the MySQL team on how to use it for my project in Visual Studio 2019.

I've done the following in my current project:

1. I sat the project configuration to "release" and to "x64".
2. Added the additional include directories.
3. Added the additional library directories.
4. Added **mysqlcppconn.lib, libmysql.lib** to additional dependencies.

Now after I save everything and continue with my project I still have issues including the needed files from to use. It doesn't seem like Visual Studio is including any of the files I've linked to.

Does anyone have had any similar issues or did I maybe do something wrong? I've tried to put it in different directories too, in case maybe the location URL was too long or something.

Comment: what issues? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Well, for one. When I try to include the .h files I need to make a conection the database, it gives me this error "Cannot open source file "mysql_connection.h". While I understand what that error message means I just don't udnberstand why VC19 won't detect the additional folders I added.

Comment: is `mysql_connection.h` in the folder you've added?

Comment: Indeed, it is. Though, its located within another folder. Is that an issue?

Comment: Jesus christ I'm dumb. I forgot to add which directory it is in from the include line. Thank you so much Alan for your help!!